# Python - JIRA installation Error code1

Tags: python-2.7, jira

I'm new to this community but have been looking up useful coding answers on this site before.
I tried to install Jira with pip and easy_install but returned with error -- Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
Really need some advise on how else I can install Jira package or resolve the error code 1 issue.
Thanks!

Comment: Post the complete installation log.

Comment: C:\Users\nadine>pip install jira
Downloading/unpacking jira
  Running setup.py egg_info for package jira
    ERROR:root:Error parsing
----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1